# Como ler da entrada padrão caracteres em um encoding específico?

Tags: python, string, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou usando a função `input()` para ler um texto da entrada padrão. O programa será executado com redirecionamento de IO em sistema linux, da seguinte forma:

```
python arquivo.py < in.put > out.put
```

O arquivo `in.put`, no entando, está em ISO-8859-1. O código problemático é simplesmente o seguinte:

```
string = input()
```

Tentei resolver, sem sucesso, aplicando os métodos `decode()` e `encode()`, das seguintes formas (conforme vi como possíveis soluções para o mesmo erro em outros casos relatados):

```
# 1o teste
string = input().decode('latin1').encode('utf8')

# 2o teste
string = input()
string.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
```

Em todos os testes, o erro retornado é o seguinte:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

O byte `0xe7`, a propósito, é um "ç". Como resolvo esse problema sem alterar os encodings originais dos arquivos de entrada e saída?

Informo que a execução do programa será automatizada, portanto, a entrada de dados deve permancer via standard input, estando fora de questão entrada via leitura de arquivo com `open('file')`.

Answer (score 1):

Há duas possibilidades, depende da versão do Python.

A partir do Python 3.7 é possível [mudar o *encoding* usado pela entrada padrão](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure):

```py
import sys

sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='iso-8859-1')
string = input()
print(string)
```

Para versões anteriores a 3.7, basta criar um [`io.TextIOWrapper`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

```py
import io
import sys

input_stream = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='iso-8859-1')
string = input_stream.read()
print(string)
```

---

Mas no seu caso, como você também quer escrever, acredito que queira que o arquivo de saída também esteja no mesmo *encoding*. Neste caso, basta setar o *encoding* também no `stdout`.

Python >= 3.7:

```py
import sys

sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='iso-8859-1')
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='iso-8859-1')
string = input()
print(string)
```

Python < 3.7:

```py
import io
import sys

input_stream = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='iso-8859-1')
output_stream = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding='iso-8859-1')
string = input_stream.read()
output_stream.write(string)
```

Vale notar também que você pode usar *encodings* diferentes para a entrada e saída.

---

Referência: [*Python 3: How to specify stdin encoding*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16549332)